# Evaluation of math formula in Python (with custom variable names and subscripts)

Tags: python, math

I need to evaluate a bunch of math formulas (string format) for a time series for example:

```
" y = 0.5 * gdp[t] + 0.2 * ln( sp500[t-2] ) "
```

The math formula has two elements I need to take care of:

- Custom variable names (e.g. `gdp`) that refer to a time series / array
- Variable subscripts to denote indices such as `t-1` or `t-2` for a time series

Does anyone have an relatively robust/efficient way to evaluate this formula to a number for a given input (i.e. such as t = 5).  Ideally a fast approach but that is a luxury item.

Comment: Have you considered using `eval`?

Comment: Does eval evaluate brackets as arrays with indices?

Comment: As long as what comes before the brackets is a list or something that implements `__getitem__`, yes. `eval` takes arbitrary Python code. You can also set exactly what objects/functions the evaluated code will have access to using its arguments. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#eval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to use `gdp` and `sp500`, but this is an example with `eval` to get you started:

```
import math

s = "0.5 * gdp[t] + 0.2 * ln( sp500[t-2] ) "
gdp = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
sp500 = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
t = 5
ln = lambda x: math.log(x)

y = eval(s)
print y # prints 2.71972245773
```

Comment: Beautiful thank you.  Didn't know eval had the ability to resolve arrays.